# How to pivoting column to row, also turn column header into row value in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  tutorial.worldwide_earthquakes
```

[image: before]

And I want reformat become like this,

[image: after]

I think I should use CROSS JOIN to pivoting column header to row value (year_2000 to 2000), and transpose number of eartquake into n value. Very appreciate for any clue or help.

Note: You can try this dataset on Mode

Comment: Thank you for reminder, sorry I missed it. I am using Mode app to run that query

Comment: "I think I should use CROSS JOIN" - Generally, joins make datasets wider, and you want to make your dataset narrower (and by consequence, longer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `union all`:

```
SELECT magnitude, 2000 as year, year_2000 as n
FROM tutorial.worldwide_earthquakes
UNION ALL
SELECT magnitude, 2001 as year, year_2001 as n
FROM tutorial.worldwide_earthquakes
UNION ALL
. . .
```

The query ends with a `SELECT`, not a `UNION ALL`.

But in Postgres, I would recommend a lateral join:

```
SELECT we.magnitude, v.year, v.n
FROM tutorial.worldwide_earthquakes we CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (2000, year_2000),
             (2001, year_2001),
             . . .
     ) v(year, n);
```

The `. . .` continues the pattern (and the last does not end in a comma).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I tried this on mode and give error message

Comment: Looks like something went wrong with your query.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "LIMIT"
  Position: 1405
  ALL
LIMIT 100
^

Comment: @IdoYudhatama . . . There is no `LIKMIT` in this query so something very strange is going on.  I suspect the query is being munged between what you type in and what the database gets.

Comment: I've tried to uncheck limit by 100 and the different error message still happen

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Position: 1404
UNION 
  ALL
    ^

Comment: The `...` in gordon's answer means "you have to finish off the pattern yourself". Do not end your SQL with UNION ALL (when you write union all something has to come after it). It's like you said "how do I add up all the numbers from 1 to 10?" and Gordon said "you go 1+2+3+ ..." and you didn't finish the pattern off, or you did, but you wrote "1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+" and left a trailing plus - the `UNION ALL` is like `+`

Comment: Yes, I missed. I end up with UNION ALL statement. Thank you @CaiusJard

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff both of your solutions really work. Very appreciate